# Migrating Spring cloud data flow server with Oracle Database

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to migrate spring-cloud-dataflow server that is currently using h2 database with oracle database. I modified the spring-cloud-dataflow.jar by adding ojdbc jar into boot-inf/lib directory with the help of jar commands. I am able to start the server also.

The problem that I am facing is when I am launching a task I am getting error saying task_execution_manifest table does not exist.

I have changed the datasource properties to point to oracle db and I can see tables getting created and entries being made to table such as app_registration. I saw the migration scripts from github repo of same but I don't see the create table script of task_execution_manifest.

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error. From where this table is coming. Where I can find script for same table.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By default SCDF uses Flyway to run a set of scripts that build up the DB. The base tables are usually in the earliest script and typically not vendor specific (like `V1_INITIAL_SETUP.sql`). So either use Flyway and let it handle the schema for you **OR** if you don't want to use Flyway then use can disable it and then execute some [provided schema scripts](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core/src/main/resources/schemas#bootstrap-server-with-ddl-files) to build up the DB. Here is some more info on how [SCDF handles schema](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-local-rdbms-schema).

Comment: Let's suppose I want to keep flyway property as true. Do I need to give spring.jpa.ddl-auto=create . Is this property required?? or any other property

Comment: No other properties should need to be set, the dialect of DB is determined via the jdbc url that you configure. If you are using Oracle jdbc url then the Oracle schema will be used. (EXTRA-INFO: you can also see what the default property values that SCDF sets for JPA and Flyway here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/dc1503e69be23be9ae0640f8fad19c4a0cb73c6d/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/dataflow-server-defaults.yml#L54)